# Error creating view in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to create a View containing columns `HospitalCode`, `WardNo`, `BedNo`, `DateLastServiced` and naming these columns as Hospital, Ward, Bed and Last Serviced.

```
CREATE VIEW HospitalCode, WardNo, BedNo, DateLastServiced  
AS SELECT * FROM BED, WARD
```

I'm getting this error saying I'm missing a keyword. Can anyone help please?

Comment: No JOIN between BED and WARD?

Comment: Did you at least try to read the manual before posting all your syntax errors here?

Comment: Before posting the next question please read this: http://tkyte.blogspot.de/2005/06/how-to-ask-questions.html and this: http://catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html

Answer (score 3):

You have three errors in your SQL:

1. Your syntax to create the view is wrong
2. You have no join condition between the two tables
3. You don't specifiy which column belongs to which table.

To define the name of the the columns in a view you can list them after the view name in the CREATE VIEW statement (as [documented in the manual](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_8004.htm))

```
CREATE VIEW MyView1 
(
   hospital,
   Ward, 
   Bed 
   Last_Serviced
)
AS 
SELECT bed.HospitalCode, 
       ward.WardNo, 
       bed.BedNo, 
       ward.DateLastServiced  
FROM BED
  JOIN WARD on bed.bedno = ward.bedno;
```

As you did not post the definition of the two tables involved I had to guess which column comes from which table. **You will have to adjust the select** to adjust for that missing information. But it should give you enough information

Another option to change the names of the view columns is to select the original columns using a column alias: `bed.HospitalCode as hospital`

Comment: I have changed it to this based on which columns from which table but I am now getting the error ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

Comment: CREATE VIEW MyView1   
(  
   hospital,  
   Ward,     
   Bed   
   Last_Serviced  
)  
AS   
SELECT ward.HospitalCode,     
       bed.WardNo,   
       bed.BedNo,   
       bed.DateLastServiced    
FROM BED  
  JOIN WARD on bed.bedno = ward.bedno;

Comment: @jeremy: You're missing a comma between `Bed` and `Last_Serviced`.

Comment: Ah yes thanks, I'm now getting this error: ORA-00904: "WARD"."BEDNO": invalid identifier

Comment: @jeremy: Your questions are incredibly basic.  You might find it helpful to look over some beginners' tutorials?

Comment: I'm working on a tutorial at the moment, I'm just struggling with it

Comment: @jeremy: I had to guess which columns belong to which table. Therefor it was very likely that my example contains an error (as I have pointed out). The next time first read the manual, then read the manual again, then post a question with all necessary information.

Answer (score 0):

You missed name for view try this:

```
CREATE VIEW MyView1 AS SELECT HospitalCode, WardNo, BedNo, DateLastServiced  
 FROM BED, WARD
```

Also I'm not sure about SELECT, because I don't have structure of your tables.

**UPDATE**

> ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined

This error means that both tables that both tables BED, WARD has same column names, so oracle can not determine which one to use.

Post output of

```
DESCRIBE TABLE BED;
DESCRIBE TABLE WARD;
```

Comment: I get this from what you have put: ORA-00918: column ambiguously defined

Comment: @rkosegi, you're suggesting the OP does a Cartesian join, which is almost definitely not what they wanted.

Comment: @Ben , you are correct, I mentioned in my answer that I'm not sure about what OP want to select, so I asked him to post structure of tables to construct right query.

Comment: I have sorted it guys, thanks for your help and input much appreciated!